# What's the optimal observation count per category for Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data

I'm seeking some advice or references concerning the optimal number of observations required for each category within a categorical variable, specifically for machine learning projects. To give an example, consider a column labeled "color", which encompasses three categories: red, green, and blue. I've encountered a general rule suggesting that a minimum of 20 observations per category is recommended, meaning that I would need at least 20 observations (rows) with green, red or blue. However, I'm interested in exploring this topic more deeply and would love to hear the community's opinions on this matter. Are there any studies, literature, or research findings that offer more comprehensive guidance or validate this rule of thumb? Any insights or suggested readings on how many entries or rows would be ideally necessary for categories such as red, green, and blue in a dataset would be highly valued. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: **1**. What are you optimizing? $\,$ **2**. Given estimates become more precise as sample size increases, why would there necessarily be an upper limit? (*which leads to* ...)  $\,$  **3**. What are you assuming about the situation?